# Copy the line based on search criteria

Tags: shell, awk, ksh

I have a `file1` that contains :

```
apple_phones.csv
apple_ipad.csv
apple_mac.csv
```

Need to copy n lines to another file `file2`

Code tried : `awk 'NR==1' "$file1" > "$file2"`

This creates file2 with first line from file1.

However , when i do `awk 'NR==4' "$file1" > "$file2"` it creates empty file `file2`.

In this case if file1 doesn't have line 4 or line 4 doesn't have "apple" in the beginning , i don;t want file 2 to be created.

Comment: The redirection creates the file automatically. just typing `> file2` will create the file. You can look at the `printf(fmt_str, args) > "/path/to/file"` feature of awk`, but you'll have to add conditional logic to prevent it printing as needed. Good luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
awk 'NR==4 && $0 ~ /^apple/ {print > "file2"}' file1
```

When condition is true, it will print to `file2` else there is no printing and no new file created.